# What do Sri Vaishnava commentaries say about Dasharatha's use of "śrīmān"?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

In the Ayodhya Kanda of the Ramayana, when Dasharatha decides to make Rama the Yuvaraja or crown prince, he makes the following [announcement](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ayodhya/sarga3/ayodhya_3_frame.htm) to the people of Ayodhya:

> caitraḥ **śrīmān** ayaṃ māsaḥ puṇyaḥ puṣpitakānanaḥ । 
>   yauvarājyāya rāmasya sarvamevopakalpyatām ॥
>
> This is the **glorious** and auspicious month of Chaitra, in which the forests bloom with flowers. Let all arrangements be made for the coronation of Rama as crown prince.

Now at 29 minute mark of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uP0opsiewdc), the Sri Vaishnava lecturer U. Ve. Pudukottai Vasu Swami says there is a deeper significance to Dasharatha's use of the word "śrīmān" (translated from Tamil):

> Dasharatha said, "caitraḥ śrīmān ayaṃ māsaḥ puṇyaḥ puṣpitakānanaḥ". When?  When Dasharatha decided to do a coronation for Rama, he called the people of Ayodhya together and told this verse ""caitraḥ śrīmān ayaṃ māsaḥ".  He called the month "śrīmān māsaḥ".  He could have said "the month of Chaitra".  He said "śrīmān māsaḥ".  If it is asked why he said "śrīmān māsaḥ", it's to celebrate the month since it's the month in which the supreme lord of all who is the master of all these Jivatmas is obtained.

I think the idea is that Dasharatha is praising the month of Chaitra because it is the month in which the people of Ayodhya are going to obtain Rama, who as an incarnation of Vishnu is the supreme lord of all the worlds, as their Yuvaraja.  I'd like greater clarity on this though.  So my question is, what do Sri Vaishnava commentaries on the Valmiki Ramayana say about this verse?

The Sri Vaishnava Acharyas Periyavachan Pillai and Govindaraja both wrote commentaries on the Valmiki Ramayana.  Do either of them discuss the use of the word ""śrīmān" in this verse?